# How to upgrade Ubuntu to a specific version?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 16.10

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.3 and I want to upgrade to 16.10. However, when I follow any instructions to upgrade via the command line or through the GUI it only gives me the option to upgrade to 17.04.

Can anyone explain to me how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is that 16.10 is [end of life](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/07/20/ubuntu-16-10-yakkety-yak-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2017/) as of July 20 2017. Therefore the upgrader will not offer it up to you as a choice.